# How do I run JBoss 4.2.3 in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, jboss

How do I run jboss 4.2.3 in debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the regular JVM options to enable remote debugging?

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTS%
```

That the usual way to enable remote debugging.

This page displays how to remote debug various app. server and is fairly recent:

[Remote debugging with eclipse](http://www.jacoozi.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=119&Itemid=134)